# How to Get Image Properties From File Directory in PHP

Tags: php

I am using following code to display images in a directory on the page

```
$dirname = "img/data/new/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" data-size=""/><br />';
}
```

which is working fine but I also need to get access to each image name to be displayed in `alt=""` and image size in `data-size=""`. Can you please let me know how to use `getimagesize()` or `getImageProperties()` here?

Comment: Wouldn't the image file name (without the dirname and .png) be the image name?

Comment: @Adib "***$size = getimagesize($dirname.$image) would do the trick for data-size***" are you sure ? At this point `$size` will be an ***array*** containing `$width, $height, $type, $attr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the dimensions of an image file, you need to provide its `path` to [getimagesize()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), to get the `filename` for `alt`, you can use [basename()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php), i.e.:

```
$dirname = "img/data/new/";
$website = "https://mysite/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
foreach($images as $image) {
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image); //get the $width, $height of the image
$filename = basename($image); // get the filename for alt
echo <<< LOL
<img src="{$website}{$dir}{$image}" alt="$filename" data-size="$width:$height"/><br />
LOL;
}
```

Comment: couple of missing semi-colons in there btw.

Comment: `$filename = basename($image)` that should have one too, I do believe ;-)

Answer (score 1):

getimagesize($filename) returns array of 4 elements. First one is width,second height,third type,fourth html attributes(width="xxx" height="xxx")

now you can fetch them like :

```
list($imageWidth,$imageHeight,$imageType,$imageAttributes) = getimagesize($image);
```

Comment: Thanks Erol, this is working but how about getting the image name?